# What kind of security for retrieving JSONP on mobile app from remote server?

Tags: javascript, php, json, angularjs, cordova

I'm making a mobile application with angularjs + phonegap that retrieves json using jsonp from my remote website (ie: website.com/jsondata.php?callback=CALLBACK)

I got it all working, but I don't like the idea that anyone can go into this php file and take this data.

I'm a complete novice when it comes to data security, so I was wondering, what options do I have to make this data less publicly retrievable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use HTTP authentication as describe on the php manual. 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

For example then you can access the data using a username and password

Comment: Thanks for the response! Do you know if there is a way I can use php authentication without it prompting me for a username/password? Like maybe send the username/password in the url or via some other sort of mechanism? I just don't want the user to be prompted each time.